# p-n diode, Power as a function of the logarithm of the circuit resistance

Tags: semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

in a circuit comprised of p-n diode and with characteristic Ohmic resistance making the diode's resistance negligible , we have for the current passing through the diode

$I=I_s(exp(Ve/kT)-1)$

where $I_s$ is the saturation current, $V$ is the difference in potential at the ends of the diode, $e$ is the elementary charge, $k$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is the temperature.

we can thus define the Power $P$ and the resistance $R$ by

$P = IV = V(I_s(exp(Ve/kT)-1)$

$R = V/I = V(I_s(exp(Ve/kT)-1)^{-1}$

By realizing a circuit comprised of an irradiated diode, a resistance box, and a couple of multimeters, it is possible to measure $P$ at various $R$ and constant $T$.

It happens so that, plotting $P(lnR)$, the data plots look very much superimposable to a distribution function of some kind: this hypotesis,bearing in mind that $I_s$ can be put equal to $1$, requires that there exists a function so that

$f(lnV-ln(exp(Ve/kT)-1))=V((exp(Ve/kT)-1)$

is there such a function? If yes, how is it found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your last equation is basically a definition of the function *f*. But if you want to get rid of the big mess in the argument of the function and replace it with a simple *x* so that you have *f(x)* equal to some expression, then that's possible, too.

I defined a variable x to be equal to the expression $ln(V)−ln(exp(Ve/kT)−1)$ in the argument of your function. Then I solved this equation for *V*, so I had *V* equal to some complicated expression including the desired variable *x*. Then this expression for *V* was substituted in for all appearances of *V* on the right side of your equation above. The resulting expression for *f(x)* is given by:

$f(x)=\frac{e^{-x} \left(k t W\left(-\frac{\alpha  e^{x-\frac{\alpha  e^x}{k t}}}{k t}\right)+\alpha 
   e^x\right)^2}{\alpha ^2}$

where *W* is the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Yes, it is big and complicated mess, isn't it? Also, note that I wrote the electron charge here as $\alpha$ instead of *e* in order to avoid confusion between the traditional symbol for electron charge and Euler's constant "e".

(Note: No, I did not do the mathematical manipulations for this by hand. I used Mathematica.)

Actual Mathematica Procedure (Note that electron charge 'e' is replaced by symbol 'a' for readability and to avoid confusion with Eulerian 'e'):

```
eqn1 = x == Log[v] - Log[Exp[v*a/(k*t)] - 1]  (* define x to be the argument of f *)
sol = First[Solve[eqn1, v]]   (* solve for v as a function of x *)
expression1 = v*(Exp[v*a/(k*t)] - 1) (* this is what the function f is supposed to equal *)
new expression = expression1 /. sol (* substitute the solution v(x) into all v's in expression1 *)
FullSimplify[newexpression] (* Simplify the resulting complicated expression *)
TraditionalForm[%]  (* Put it into traditional form so that it is easier to read *)
```

Comment: Thank you!
I'm trying to replicate everything you did (plus the saturation current) using mathematica, but i can't seem to find the  command you used to find V=V(x).
Any pointers? Thank you again!

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have the Mathematica file I used but I believe that I simply used Mathematica's "Solve" command to find V(x) given the equation x=ln(V)−ln(exp(Ve/kT)−1).

Comment: Had no luck in that, and looking around it appears out of the Scope of the function.
Would you mind posting a sample input?
I realize this is not a space for discussing Mathematica.

Comment: OK, I added the actual Mathematica calculation lines into the answer.